# Column width option not available in specific worksheets

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the following problem. I have a Excel document with several worksheets. In the February worksheet I can adjust the column width option. I get the double-sided arrow between the two letters. But in the other worksheets I can't change the column width.

[image]

In all the other worksheets of this Excel file, this option is not available. **I can't find the option to enable/disable adjusting the column width.**

At the moment it looks like this when I hover my mouse over the place where the double arrow should appear.

[image]

** The whole worksheet is not protected.**

---

Edit:

The option to change the properties of the columns are greyed out. For all columns.

[image]

Comment: Looking at your second screenshot, I think the worksheet is either protected (which you say it isn't) - or maybe it is set as a "Shared Workbook" which multiple users can edit at the same time. If this is the case, see  [this article](http://www.wikihow.com/Unshare-an-Excel-Workbook)

Comment: Sharing your workbook will be very much helpful, since for the case there are too many ifs to guess....

Answer (score 1):

Normally you only see this when the worksheet/workbook is protected. 
Try it with a macro. For example:

```
Sub Test()
    Columns("A:C").ColumnWidth = 20
End Sub
```

When protected then you get a message that it is unable to set the ColumnWidth property.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume the column is locked. Right click on the column and select Format Cells. Then select the Protection tab.

Comment: thank you for your fast answer. I added an other screenshot to my question. The options for adjusting the properties of the columns are greyed out.

Comment: Do you have ownership of this file, or does some one else administer / distribute it? At our place of work, we used to hide columns or fix widths and prevent other users from gaining access.